# How can I zoom in and out in mac photo viewer with mouse wheel

Tags: macos, shortcut

When I open a photo in mac, I can zoom in and out using the command and + or command and - key combinations. Is there a way to zoom in and out where the mouse cursor is using the mouse's scroll wheel?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is describing how to do this using both mouse and keyboard, you will be able to hold a key on your keyboard while you scroll with your mouse to zoom.

For this, go to **System Settings** > **Accessibility** > **Zoom**. Then, turn on "**Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom**". Now, click on "**Modifier key for scroll gesture**" (it will show a popup menu) then choose the modifier key you want (the one you will hold when scrolling to zoom) between <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>.

Note that you can also scroll with your keyboard while pressing the chosen modifier key as well, it will do the same actions.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do in the photo viewer? Are there any other apps that can achieve this?

Comment: @MOON This also works in Photos for me (that's why I have answered). Just follow the steps in the answer and it'll work in Photos normally. I don't know if there's other apps to do this, sorry.